# All print jobs "Processing" indefinitely on HP Office Jet Pro

Tags: printing, hp

I have an HP Office Jet Pro to which I am trying to network print. All jobs that I send to it never print and if I check with the Document print Status window, the status is listed as processing. I could print things about a year ago but not any more.

Things I have tried:

- Restarting my computer.
- Restarting the printer.
- Checking to make sure I have the right IP address.
- Pinging the printer's ip address. That does work.
- Trying to "add" the printer a second time.

I have ensured that, under printer policies, the "Enabled" check box is checked.
I tried setting up printing from a windows virtual box inside my Ubuntu machine. I was able to print part of a test page, though it also gave me an error message.

I will add that my office mates are able to print to this computer using different computers.
I can print to other printers on my network.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Anybody? I still have this problem and it seems pretty mysterious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Things seem to have sort of magically started working, when I made a new connection to the printer. I did the following:

- Opened **Printers** from dash
- Added a printer
- Clicked **Find network printer**
- Entered the printer's ip address in the **host** box and clicked find
- Under **connection**, selected **HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP)**
- Proceeded through the rest of the add printer steps following the prompts.

The connection that got created seemed to work.